# Expect status [201] from Google Storage. But got status 302

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage with the help of a django application. I wrote this **create_gcs_file** function that gets called in my view:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

def create_gcs_file(filename, data):
    with gcs.open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)

    blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename
    return blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

I call this function in a view and pass it a filename, and some file.read() data as parameters. [Here](http://pastebin.com/bqV0JMEy) is the view code I have written that makes use of this.

But when I upload the file I get this error:

`Expect status [201] from Google Storage. But got status 302`

The debug page shows that the error occurs at this line:

`with gcs.open(filename, 'w') as f:`

P.S: I get this error when running my app with the Google App Engine SDK 1.8.5 locally.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @GeoJacob: It guess i did not, else I would have posted a solution here. I am off touch with app engine / cloud storage currently.

Comment: Okay I got the solution for my problem, may be it will be useful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

I also had gone though this same situation, In my case the real problem was in model field.
Actual field was like:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='../../static/cars')
```

And later I change the upload to option as;

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/cars')
```

Now my problem solved and it is working fine now.